# How to create AVL

Tags: c, data-structures

I enter several numbers(2,1,4,5,9,3,6,7),after I enter the number '3', there something wrong,the function can not return correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct AVLNode
{
    int data;
    int height;
    struct AVLNode *LChild;
    struct AVLNode *RChild;
}*AVLTree;
typedef struct AVLNode *Position;

static int Height(Position T)
{
    if (T == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
        return T->height;
}

static Position SingleLeft(Position k2)
{
    Position k1;
    k1 = k2->LChild;
    k2->LChild = k1->RChild;
    k1->RChild = k2;

    k2->height = max(Height(k2->LChild), Height(k2->RChild)) + 1;
    k1->height = max(Height(k1->LChild), Height(k1->RChild)) + 1;

    return k1;
}

static Position SingleRight(Position k1)
{
    Position k2;
    k2 = k1->RChild;
    k1->RChild = k2->LChild;
    k2->LChild = k1;

    k1->height = max(Height(k1->LChild), Height(k1->RChild)) + 1;
    k2->height = max(Height(k2->LChild), Height(k2->RChild)) + 1;

    return k2;
}

static Position DoubleLeft(Position k3)
{
    k3->LChild = SingleRight(k3->LChild);

    return SingleLeft(k3);
}

static Position DoubleRight(Position k1)
{
    k1->RChild = SingleLeft(k1->RChild);

    return SingleRight(k1);
}

void PrePrint(AVLTree T)
{
    if (T != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d  ", T->data);
        PrePrint(T->LChild);
        PrePrint(T->RChild);
    }
}

AVLTree Insert(int x, AVLTree T)
{
    if (T == NULL)
    {
        T = (AVLTree)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLNode));
        T->data = x;
        T->LChild = T->RChild = NULL;
    }
    else if (x < T->data)
    {
        T->LChild = Insert(x, T->LChild);
        if (Height(T->LChild) - Height(T->RChild) == 2)
        {
            if (x<T->LChild->data)
                T = SingleLeft(T);
            else
                T = DoubleLeft(T);
        }
    }
    else if (x > T->data)
    {
        T->RChild = Insert(x, T->RChild);
        if (Height(T->RChild) - Height(T->LChild) == 2)
        {
            if (x>T->RChild->data)
                T = SingleRight(T);
            else
                T = DoubleRight(T);
        }
    }

    T->height = max(Height(T->LChild), Height(T->RChild)) + 1;

    return T;
}
```

I think there is something wrong in my main function, I think I shouldn't write

```
 T=(AVLTree)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLNode));
    T->LChild = T->RChild = NULL;
```

those code in mian function, I try to add a 'Init' function, but it doesn't work. It always said "'T' is being used without initialized"

```
int main()
{
    AVLTree T;
    T=(AVLTree)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLNode));I think there is wrong
    T->LChild = T->RChild = NULL;
    int x;
    printf("please enter the data(0 to quit):");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    T->data = x;
    while (x != 0)
    {
        Insert(x, T);
        printf("enter a number(0 to quit):");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    } 
    PrePrint(T);
}
```

Comment: `T=(AVLTree)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLNode));` --> `T=malloc(sizeof(struct AVLNode));`

Comment: Can you be clearer about what your problem is? What do you mean by "the function cannot return correctly"? What happens that you didn't expect to happen (or doesn't happen that you did expect to happen)?

Comment: I agree that it would be nicer to put the initialization in a separate function. We won't be able to tell you what went wrong when you tried to do so, without seeing the code. (But I'll make a guess: perhaps it has something to do with how you made your `AVLTree` object available to the `Init` function; perhaps you tried to pass it in by value rather than by pointer, or something. A better alternative might have been to make your init function *return* an `AVLTree *`.)

Comment: Seeing as how this is C, do not cast the return of `malloc`.

Comment: Your `main` function begins by making a tree with exactly one node, whose `data` is the first number entered. Then, the first time around the `while` loop, it inserts *that same number* into the tree. That probably isn't what you want to do. (But it doesn't sound like the problem you're actually asking us about.)

Comment: Oh, one other question: Is this something you're doing for a class? I ask because (1) it's the kind of thing people often get required to do in a data-structures-and-algorithms course and (2) if it is, you should say so because what kind of answer is most helpful may differ a little depending on why you're doing this.

Comment: After I enter the number '3', The correct root data should be '4', and it is correct in all functions except 'main' function, when the procedure runs back to main function, the root data is '2'.I am sorry that I can not describe it exactly.

Comment: You said my tree begins with a exactly node, I think maybe this is the reason why this wrong happen. So does that means it cant be modify?

Comment: I said that your tree begins with *exactly one* node. There's nothing wrong with that. The observation I was making is that you put your first `x` into the tree twice: once when constructing that first node, and once by calling `Insert`.

Comment: when writing code, use meaningful variable names.  I.E. names that indicate contents or usage or both.  names like `T` and `k2` and `k1` and `x` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  (for the calls to `scanf()` in the posted code, any returned value other than 1 indicates some error occurred.

Comment: when writing `typedef`s, etc, do not hide the fact that some name is a pointer.  (`AVLTree` and `Position` being examples) as that leads to mis-understandings, makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Why declare more than one type name for `struct AVLNode`?

Comment: the `max()` is not defined within your code and is not part of either of the #include'd header files.

Comment: when performing an `insert`, (and similar such operations) it is possible/probable that the `head` pointer will need to be updated.  To perform that operation, the passed in `AVLTree` needs to be `**` not `*` so the callers' pointer can be updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I change `Insert(x, T);` to `T=Insert(x, T);`, in this way, I solved my problems. It's that a correct way?   I will  not declare more than one type. But "do not hide the fact that some name is a pointer." I can't understand clearly, and could you tell me how to use `typedef` exactly, please give me an example.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your insertion makes a new *root* node, this fact is not propagated back to `main` in any way. The value of `T` inside the `Insert` function changes, but `main` has its own variable called `T` that isn't changed, and that's the one that you then use to print out the tree.

I notice that your `Insert` function returns an `AVLTree`, but when `main` calls it it doesn't do anything with the return value.

(This is not the only thing that's amiss in your code, but it would be a good place to start.)

Comment: I know what your means, although I don't know the correct way to solve it, thanks for your help.